# Cleaning date string format in R

Tags: r

I would like to clean a date string, it has this form

```
> print(date)
[1] " 29-12-2014 06:37 UTC"
```

And I need only 29-12-2014

Comment: When reading your data into R, use the `strip.white = TRUE` parameter in the `read.table` or `read.csv` call to remove leading and lagging spaces right away.

Comment: @EnricAgudPique If you have already read it with spaces, `str_trim` from `library(stringr)` would be useful for removing the lead/lag spaces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing date format to "%d/%m/%Y"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `as.Date` (assuming your data are already stored as a "date" object).

```
x <- Sys.time()
x
# [1] "2014-12-29 12:35:18 IST"
as.Date(x)
# [1] "2014-12-29"
```

If your data are not currently in a standard date format, please use `strptime` to convert it to a date format first, after which you could also use `format`

```
xx <- " 29-12-2014 06:37 UTC"
as.Date(strptime(xx, format = " %d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"))
# [1] "2014-12-29"

## format would let you specify the order you want
format(strptime(xx, format = " %d-%m-%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
# [1] "29-12-2014"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have the strings not in the `as.POSIXct` format, an option using `regex` would be

```
 str1 <- " 29-12-2014 06:37 UTC"
 sub('[ ]+([^ ]+) .*', '\\1', str1)
 #[1] "29-12-2014"
```

Or using `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy_hm(str1),'%d-%m-%Y')
#[1] "29-12-2014"
```

This would also take `multiple` formats

```
 str2 <- c(str1, '29.12.14 06/37 UTC')
 format(dmy_hm(str2), '%d-%m-%Y')
 #[1] "29-12-2014" "29-12-2014"
```

Comment: Interesting this library lubridate, i will check it, it helps also

Answer (score 0):

df$newdate <- month(as.POSIXlt(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))

df$newdate <- month(as.POSIXlt(df$Date, format = "%d-%m-%Y"))