# Converting dates in R

Tags: r, date

My dates in my data set in a CSV file are in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`. When inputted to R they are factors and are in the format `"01-Aug-12"`.

I've tried the following:

```
as.Date(x=df$Date.of.Visit, format="%d %b %Y")
```

All I get returned is NA. Could this be because the year R sees is not 4 digits? ('12 rather than 2012).

Comment: There are dashes in your data format `"%d-%b-%Y"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing date format to "%d/%m/%Y"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y)

Comment: @MaxZoom whoops! This book i'm following has it wrong then. I added dashes ran that code and it returned "0012-10-30". (date was October 30th, 2012).

Comment: Oh sorry @MaxZoom tagged the wrong person in that comment above^^. But regardless R for dummies 2nd edition. They put this as an example which I followed: 

as.Date("5 Aug 2016", format = "%d %b %Y")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R documentation for as.Date:

```
## read in date info in format 'ddmmmyyyy'
## This will give NA(s) in some locales; setting the C locale
## as in the commented lines will overcome this on most systems.
## lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
x <- c("1jan1960", "2jan1960", "31mar1960", "30jul1960")
z <- as.Date(x, "%d%b%Y")
## Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
z
```

In your case just do:

```
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
as.Date(x=df$Date.of.Visit, format="%d-%b-%y") 
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lct)
```

Comment: tried this out and worked perfectly. Thanks @HubertL

Answer (score 0):

Or, using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
df$realdate <- ymd(df$Date.of.Visit)
```

Then the format is unimportant.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I introduce a date with the following format: "01MAY2018". I obtain the warning/error: "Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found."