# formatting the date in R

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a date value as follows

```
"'2015-10-24'"
class Character
```

I am trying to format this value such that it looks like this `'10/24/2015'`

I know how to use `noquote` function and strip the quotes and `gsub` function to replace the `-` with `/` but I am not sure how to switch the year, date and month such that it looks like this '10/24/2015'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check if this helps, 
df$ddate<-strftime(df$ddate,"%d/%m/%Y")
df$bdate<-strftime(strptime(df$bdate,"%d/%m/%y"),"%d/%m/%Y")
df$wdate<-strftime(strptime(df$wdate,"%d/%m/%y"),"%d/%m/%Y")

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y
worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can convert to `Date` class after removing the `'` with `gsub`, and then use `format` to get the expected output

```
format(as.Date(gsub("'", '', v1)), "'%m/%d/%Y'")
#[1] "'10/24/2015'" "'10/25/2015'"
```

Or without using the `gsub` to remove `'`, we can specify the `'` also in the `format` within `as.Date`

```
format(as.Date(v1, "'%Y-%m-%d'"), "'%m/%d/%Y'") 
#[1] "'10/24/2015'" "'10/25/2015'"
```

This can be made more compact if we are using `library(lubridate)`

```
library(lubridate)
format(ymd(v1), "'%m/%d/%Y'")
#[1] "'10/24/2015'" "'10/25/2015'"
```

If we don't need the `'` in the output, we don't have to specify that in the format,

```
format(ymd(v1), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "10/24/2015" "10/25/2015"
```

---

Or we can do this using only `gsub` by capturing the characters as a group.  In the below code, we capture the first 4 characters (`.{4}`) as a group by wrapping with parentheses followed by matching the `-`, then capturing the next two characters, followed by `-`, and capturing the last two characters.  In the replacement, we can shuffle the capture groups as per the requirement.  In this case, the second capture group should come first (`\\2`) followed by `/`, then the third (`\\3`) and so on...

```
 gsub('(.{4})-(.{2})-(.{2})', '\\2/\\3/\\1', v1)
 #[1] "'10/24/2015'" "'10/25/2015'"
```

To avoid the quotes,

```
 gsub('.(.{4})-(.{2})-(.{2}).', '\\2/\\3/\\1', v1)
 #[1] "10/24/2015" "10/25/2015"
```

---

In addition, there are other ways such as splitting the string

```
vapply(strsplit(v1, "['-]"), function(x) paste(x[c(3,4,2)], collapse='/'), character(1))
#[1] "10/24/2015" "10/25/2015"
```

or extracting the numeric part with `str_extract_all` and `paste`ing as before.

```
 library(stringr)
 vapply(str_extract_all(v1, '\\d+'), function(x) 
               paste(x[c(2,3,1)], collapse='/'), character(1))   
 #[1] "10/24/2015" "10/25/2015"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("'2015-10-24'", "'2015-10-25'")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the function `strftime` to get the result

```
d <- "'2015-10-24'"
strftime(as.Date(gsub("'", "", d)), "%m/%d/%Y")

# [1] "10/24/2015"
```