# Split a character and add other string in R

Tags: r, string, character

I have the following character `selectedMonths <- c("201501")`

How can I get two strings

```
"2015-01-01 00:00:00"
```

and

```
"2015-01-31 23:59:59"
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem in more detail. What assumptions do you want to make when transforming one character string into another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing date format to "%d/%m/%Y"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y)

Comment: I have only the character "201501" that means January 2015. The first part is year 2015 and the last two are the month (January in this case). I want to split my given character "201501" into "2015-01", then I need a add it to "2015-01-01 00:00:00" and other "2015-01-31 23:59:59"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(zoo)
paste(as.Date(as.yearmon(selectedMonths, format = '%Y%m')), "00:00:00")
paste(as.Date(as.yearmon(selectedMonths, format = '%Y%m'), frac = 1), "23:59:59")
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "2015-01-01 00:00:00"
#[1] "2015-01-31 23:59:59"
```