# Extract Month and Year From Date in R

Tags: r, date

I have tried a number of methods to no avail. I have data in terms of a date (YYYY-MM-DD) and am trying to get in terms of just the month and year, such as: MM-YYYY or YYYY-MM.

Ultimately, I would like it to look like this:

```
ID    Date         Month_Yr
1     2004-02-06   2004-02
2     2006-03-14   2006-03
3     2007-07-16   2007-07
...   ...          ...
```

I am doing this in hopes of plotting money earned on average in a month, from a number of orders, over a period of time. Any help, or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing date format to "%d/%m/%Y"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract month and year from a zoo::yearmon object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749598/extract-month-and-year-from-a-zooyearmon-object)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This will add a new column to your `data.frame` with the specified format.

```
df$Month_Yr <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y-%m")

df
#>   ID       Date Month_Yr
#> 1  1 2004-02-06  2004-02
#> 2  2 2006-03-14  2006-03
#> 3  3 2007-07-16  2007-07

# your data sample
  df <- data.frame( ID=1:3,Date = c("2004-02-06" , "2006-03-14" , "2007-07-16") )
```

a simple example:

```
dates <- "2004-02-06"

format(as.Date(dates), "%Y-%m")
> "2004-02"
```

*side note*:
the `data.table` approach can be quite faster in case you're working with a big dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Month_Yr := format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m") ]
```

Comment: The drawback of `format` is that one loses the `Date` type, it converts to `character`

Answer (score 19):

Here's another solution using a package solely dedicated to working with dates and times in R:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

(df <- tibble(ID = 1:3, Date = c("2004-02-06" , "2006-03-14", "2007-07-16")))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      ID Date      
#>   <int> <chr>     
#> 1     1 2004-02-06
#> 2     2 2006-03-14
#> 3     3 2007-07-16

df %>%
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(Date),
    Month_Yr = format_ISO8601(Date, precision = "ym")
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID Date       Month_Yr
#>   <int> <date>     <chr>   
#> 1     1 2004-02-06 2004-02 
#> 2     2 2006-03-14 2006-03 
#> 3     3 2007-07-16 2007-07
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Use substring?

```
d = "2004-02-06"
substr(d,0,7)
>"2004-02"
```

Answer (score 7):

The `zoo` package has the function of `as.yearmon` can help to convert.

```
require(zoo)

df$ym <- as.yearmon(df$date, "%Y %m")
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the **month name** and not the numbers are wanted, like in the as duplicated classified question [Extract month and year from datetime in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084375), this can be done with `format` and `%B` or `%b`.

```
date <- as.Date(c("2011-10-20", "2011-12-25", "2012-04-15"))

format(date, "%Y %B %b %m")
#[1] "2011 October Oct 10"  "2011 December Dec 12" "2012 April Apr 04"
```

Where

- `%Y` Year
- `%B` Full month name in the current locale
- `%b` Abbreviated month name in the current locale
- `%m` Month as decimal number

The documentation for the formats can be found in [`strptime`, `strftime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

In addition the month name in the current locale could be extracted using `months`

```
months(date)
#[1] "October"  "December" "April"
```

To get it in other languages [`Sys.setlocale`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) could be used.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")

format(date, "%Y %B %b %m")
#[1] "2011 Oktober Okt 10"  "2011 Dezember Dez 12" "2012 April Apr 04"

months(date)
#[1] "Oktober"  "Dezember" "April"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` package introduced the `IDate` class some time ago and `zoo`-package-like functions to retrieve months, days, etc (Check `?IDate`). so, you can extract the desired info now in the following ways:

```r
require(data.table)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                 date = c("2004-02-06" , "2006-03-14" , "2007-07-16"))
setDT(df)
df[ , date := as.IDate(date) ] # instead of as.Date()
df[ , yrmn := paste0(year(date), '-', month(date)) ]
df[ , yrmn2 := format(date, '%Y-%m') ]
```