# Change Date Format from %y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s to %Y%M%D with lubridate and mutate

Tags: r, lubridate, dplyr

I've got a `tbl_df`with two columns *StartTime* and *StopTime*. Both are `dttm`.

I want to change its format from `"%y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s"` to `"%y%m%d"`.

I've tried

```
data <- mutate(data, StartTime = ymd(StartTime), StopTime = ymd(StopTime))
```

But it returns

> > Warning messages: 1: All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

How can I do it?

*Please, don't send other questions that don't use lubridate package.*

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Month and Year From Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704212/extract-month-and-year-from-date-in-r)

Comment: @rafa.pereira no, in that question doesn't use lubridate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)


df <- data_frame(StartTime1 = "2017-04-28 12:50:45")

df %>% mutate(StartTime2 = ymd_hms(StartTime1),
              StartTime3 = as_date(StartTime2))

#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>            StartTime1          StartTime2 StartTime3
#>                 <chr>              <dttm>     <date>
#> 1 2017-04-28 12:50:45 2017-04-28 12:50:45 2017-04-28
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had a problem where the date-format was like: "2019-12-06T09:27:14".

For me ymd_hms did not work and I did not find a fitting parser, so the solution was first to string_replace the uneccessary part and then to parse to date as usual.. (and discard the original column if needed)

```
 your_df %>%mutate(date_published = 
                   str_replace(article.date_published,T\\d\\d\\:\\d\\d\\:\\d\\d', ''), 
                   date_published= ymd(date_published))%>%
           select(-contains('article.date'))
```