# R - String to Date Conversion

Tags: r, string, date, datetime

Say I have a string of date like "3/23/2016" and just want to change the format to 3/23/2016. I try:

`as.Date("3/23/2016, "%m%d%Y")` but keeps giving me NA, as well as trying other methods. Anyone know a easy/fast way to do this? 03/23/2016 is ok too.

Comment: Include the slash. `as.Date("3/23/2016, "%m/%d/%Y")`.

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks. I get it in the format 2016-03-23 now with the %m/%d%Y. Anyway I can reverse it to my originally intended date?

Comment: I think you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y

Comment: @BenBolker The title says to **Date Conversion**. I think OP is confused between different formats and a `Date` class.

Comment: I was addressing the implicit question in the comments. The answer to "how do I avoid NA" is addressed in @nicola's comment and in the posted answer. "How do I get back to my original date format?" is basically what's answered in the linked question.

Comment: But I presume OP thinks that it will preserve it's `Date` class, which it doesn't.

Comment: @sammuh I think next time also define the purpose behind what you are trying to achieve, if you want to do specific date manipulations or not. It would be clearer to get answers to your question then.

Comment: @ShwetaKamble I have a vector of date strings of "3/23/2016" format. I want to put all of it in a column in a data frame in a particular order. I'm doing data[,1][index1:index2] = dates[x] in a loop. However it's not storing them as a date but more as a numeric (even though I believe I casted the first column of the data matrix as a date

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b=as.Date(a, "%m/%d/%Y"),
```

It will give you the result then 
Try:

```
Class(b)
```

to find the format.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("3/23/2016")
#[1] "2016-03-23"
```