# How do I rearrange dates in R?

Tags: r, date

Here is just one date that I have (out of more than 6,000)

```
02/01/15
```

This is expressed as January 2nd, 2015. And *I would like the date to instead look like the following*,

```
2015/01/02
```

I read up on this thread: [Changing date format to "%d/%m/%Y"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832385/changing-date-format-to-d-m-y)

But unless my R does not work properly, none of the answers give the correct format, instead I get this output,

```
0002/01/15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
format(as.Date("02/01/15", format = "%d/%m/%y"), "%Y/%m/%d")

[1] "2015/01/02"
```

Comment: Thank you, here is what I did: df$ddate <- format(as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%y"), "%Y/%m/%d")

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is very useful for date and time manipulation

```
library(lubridate)
x <- lubridate::dmy('02/01/15')
format(x, format = ('%Y/%m/%d'))
```